# Open Office Default Font

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

I have imported a document from another Ubuntu computer (made in open office).

The other computer had the font Merriweather installed, which the present system does not. As a result my present system has defaulted to a different font. Strangely enough I prefer the default font to my previous choice of Merriweather and would like to keep it set to this even if I export this file back to the original computer (which will have Merriweather installed!).

Trouble is I have no idea which font Libre Office is currently using, in the bar at the top it says Merriweather, but this is obviously not true as it is neither installed nor looked like the font.

How do I find out what Libre Office defaults to on Ubuntu and what is the quickest way to divine which font is being used.

Failing that I attach an image below for anyone with a sharp typographic eye (but I would prefer to know how to solve this one without simply recognising the font!)

[image: unknown font]

Comment: This is why I'm learning (La)TeX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

In LibreOffices' Menu Bar go to 'Tools -> Options', which will open a pop up window, like shown in the screenshot above.

From there choose from options:

- LibreOfficeWriter -> Fonts
- LibreOfficeWriter -> Basic Fonts

You can set new fonts or simple find out, what fonts are set in your current setup.

Answer (score 3):

The font looks like DejaVu Sans.